# Is there a Python package to do constrained Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: library, python, geometry

I have a function whose range is a non-convex, simply connected region in R3. When I sample the function I know if the resulting point is on the surface of the region or not. I'd like to triangulate those samples subject to the surface constrains, i.e., the resulting tetrahedra should not "hide" surface points. The hull would not be convex, of course.

I searched around for a library. So far I found Triangle, but it only works in R2. I also found TetGen, which works in R3, but it requires to provide the surface mesh (which I don't have). Also, as far as I can see, these C/C++ libraries do not have Python bindings.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You've likely found this by now, but: https://github.com/drufat/triangle/